# How to setup continuous integration test for push notifications?

Tags: firebase, apple-push-notifications, integration-testing

I am developing a service that sends push notifications via APNS and Firebase to an app I have written. I have integration tests that run continuously (plus monitoring) to alert me if the service has a problem. Ideally these tests requests to my service would result in calls to APNS or Firebase, to test that the integration is still working. However I don't actually want APNS or Firebase to process the request, just return a 200.

Currently my service has special logic to silently drop these test requests just before making the call to APNS or Firebase.

Other services (such as email or sms) sometimes offer a magic or black hole address for testing purposes.

Is there a way to generate a special test token for APNS and Firebase that acts like a real device token (from an API point of view) buts actually does nothing but return 200?

Comment: I would really like this as well. It is a shame that FCN and APNS do not offer this facility currently.